# How to build openni_launch or rgbd_launch for ROS Hydro?

Tags: ros-hydro, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

```
  For kinect drivers, how to download and build openni_launch or rgbd_launch?

  Many thanks!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162351/how-to-build-openni_launch-or-rgbd_launch-for-ros-hydro?/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2014-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni-camera

$sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni-launch

It still works, but I am wondering that openni_launch has already been included in rgbd_launch in hydro?

---

Originally posted by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) with karma: 286 on 2014-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-05-06**:
是的。 `rgbd_launch contains all the common launch files required by a driver specific launch package such as openni_launch or freenect_launch.`   http://wiki.ros.org/rgbd_launch